# Is it safe to have visible Google Drive API keys in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am using Google drive API to download file from Google drive. I am using Javascript for that. Is it safe to have visible API keys in JS or I should use Node.js or something else? As you can see on the top of code, there are many keys (developer key, client id and app id). Is there any vulnerable in my code?

Here is my code:

```
    var developerKey = '[key]';
    var clientId = "[key]"
    var appId = "[key]";
    var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

    var pickerApiLoaded = false;
    var driveLoaded = false;
    var oauthToken;

    // Use the Google API Loader script to load the google.picker script.
    function loadPicker() {
      gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
      gapi.load('client', function () {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function () {
          driveLoaded = true;
        });
    });
    }

    function onAuthApiLoad() {
      window.gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': clientId,
            'scope': scope,
            'immediate': false
          },
          handleAuthResult);
    }

    function onPickerApiLoad() {
      pickerApiLoaded = true;
      createPicker();
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        createPicker();
      }
    }

    // Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
    function createPicker() {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        view.setMimeTypes("application/sla,application/vnd.ms-pki.stl,application/x-navistyle");
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .setAppId(appId)
            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
            .addView(view)
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
            .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .build();
         picker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }

  // A simple callback implementation.
  function pickerCallback(data) {
    if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
      var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
      downloadFile(fileId, data.docs[0].name);
    }
  }

  function downloadFile(fileId, fileName)
  {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
      fileId:fileId,
      alt:"media"
    }).then(function(resp){
        $.post("PHP/save_file.php", {Type: "stl", Filename: fileName, Data: resp.body}, function(response) {
          if (response == "OK")
          {

          }
        });
    });
  }

  function showPickerDialog(){
    loadPicker()
  }
```

Comment: You might want to check the [help center](https://security.stackexchange.com/help) to see if your question is on topic for [security.se].

Comment: Yes, you don't want them available to the client, or even in your code repository. They are like passwords.

Comment: @RaniSharim for javascript client applications they are not really like passwords.  Oauth2 for server sided is more like login and password.  Client side javascript its more like a login without a password.  The password comes in when it links to the javascript origin on the server.   CLient id and API key with regard to Javascript only really identify your application to Google.

Comment: @HereticMonkey im not really sure this qualifies as security more best practices in securing Authentication server clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you created your app on Google Developer console you created a web application.  When you created it you added a javascript origin.  As long as you set this javascript origin to the location of your webserver that the application is running on then there is no way anyone can use your client id.  If you have left it set to localhost then yes there is a risk that someone could hijack your token and use it.

As for the api key you should lock that down to a specific domain, however api keys only give you access to read public data. The amount of public data in Google Drive but someone could abuse your api key if you dont lock it down.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am using localhost for the testing. In future I will definitevelly set domain and other stuffs...

Comment: remember to accept the answer if it helped you